# React project run React native start command

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm-start

I always run project using `npm start` to start project. but i ran `npx react-native start` to start project one time and all installation process completed by my mistake. so i need to rollback that process to remove react native. is it normal or don't need to worry about it? or need to remove react native and How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just runs the metro,
you can cancel the process and that's it.

you did not need to reinstall react native